# What causes TypeERROR: Content is Null on my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom

SO,
It has been days that I am investing time on an error that I know could be solved with a line of code but because I am relatively new to coding I couldn't find a fix for this. I have a small piece of code for a collapsible list from W3 Schools, it works perfectly on W3 Schools editor but I get an `Uncaught TypeError: content is null` error while I push it to my WordPress website.
Here is the JavaScript Code:

```
window.onload=function() {
   var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
   var i;
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
}
```

And here is the CSS:

```
  .collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

And finally here is the HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Below is the console error that I get:

[image: Firefox Console]

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Try print out `this` and `this.nextElementSibling` to debug.

Comment: @slideshowp2 sorry to ask, how can i do that? As said I am relatively new to coding specially JavaScript.

Comment: In your HTML there's a button, or some other element with class "collapsible" without a next element sibling.

Comment: @Teemu it does work on W3 Schools editor after removing other elements and keeping only one button. here is the link. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible

Comment: Your code, as written, works. I'd wager that on your actual site, the `<div class="content">` or the `<button>` are being wrapped in something, which will cause the ` var content = this.nextElementSibling;` to return null.

Comment: @Xhynk any workaround to debug this issue?

Comment: @Xhynk I found out that `nextElementSibling` is returning null. What could be the reason?

Comment: Paste the actual code from your site (view-source). Clearly the `.content` element isn't immediately following the `button` element, which is required by your JS as it's written